# Can't send commands from client, but can from host. UNET

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

Help, i have made 2 models, in Unity 3D, and i have programed it so that you can choose which model you want, now on the host it works perfectly, if the client choses the first model, the host see's the client player has the first model, and so with the second. But on the client side, things arent working so good, neither model shows up, i think it has to do with the commands. Here is my code :

```
void Start() {

    if (GameObject.FindObjectOfType<ButtonScript>().Buttonn)
    {
        IsEye = true;

    }
    mybody = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    OldSpeed = Speed;
    FirstPersoncamera.sensitivity = CameraMoveSpeed;
    FirstPersoncamera.smoothing = CameraSensitivity;
    if (!GameObject.FindObjectOfType<BeSinci1>().Buttonn)
    {
        IsEye = false;

    }

    if (IsEye && isLocalPlayer) {

        CmdSetEyeParent();
    }
    if (!IsEye && isLocalPlayer)
    {
        CmdSetRobotParent();

    }
}
[Command]
public void CmdSetEyeParent() {
    RobotParent.SetActive(false);
    EyeParent.SetActive(true);
    gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().center = new Vector3(0, 2.99f, 0.06880748f);
    gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().size = new Vector3(6.42f, 9.2f, 5.52f);
    anim = EyeParent.GetComponent<Animator>();
}
[Command]
public void CmdSetRobotParent() {
    RobotParent.SetActive(true);
    EyeParent.SetActive(false);
    gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().center = new Vector3(0, 0.1912432f, 0.06880748f);
    gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().size = new Vector3(0.812993f, 3.379633f, 1.02866f);
    //anim = EyeParent.GetComponent<Animator>();
}
```

if you need more informatiton, just tell me!, i am using C#
Thanks!

Comment: I didn't understand your problem exactly but usually problem of this kind appears when models are not listed in spawnable, or when client hasn't authority.

Comment: @PierreBaret i think that client doesn't have authority, but how do i give it authority?

Comment: It is usually set from network identity component

Comment: i already pressed "Local Player Authority", is there something else i should press?